# Flutter - unboundedHeight error within ListView

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Flutter newbie here!

Currently, my Scaffold has 2 listview builders and the bottom one is giving me the unbounded height (`!constraints.hasBoundedHeight` error) issue.

I have tried using `shrinkWrap` on all 3 list views, as suggested in similar questions but I get the same error.

The only thing that works is wrapping the `FutureBuilder` in a `SizedBox`. But that seems unintuitive to me, as I would want it to ideally expand as needed and be scrollable.

`My rough solution is to maybe dynamically calculate the height based on the number of items the FutureBuilder needs, but again, I feel there should be a better solution.`

My code snippet is attached below:

```dart
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: 2,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return const SuggestCard(
                  indexKey: 'takt',
                );
              }),
          FutureBuilder<AnimeDetails>(
            future: _animeDetail,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 2, //Number of anime from list
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      var anime = snapshot.data; //Get the data from the index
                      return AnimeCard(
                        anime: anime,
                      );
                    });
              } else {
                return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: how you like to have scroll behavior

Comment: @YeasinSheikh I have 3 listViews, the second one is horizontal, the third is vertical and the first one is just an overall vertical scroll. Basically, the second listView will have a fixed height and the third one will depend on the number of elements, so I want to be able to scroll these two together (using the first listView)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent `ListView` handling scroll event for body and while second  ListView will have fixed height, you can do it like this

```dart
  return Scaffold(
        body: LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) => ListView(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: constraints.maxHeight * .3,
            child: ListView.builder(
              itemCount: 122,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text("H $index"),
            ),
          ),
          ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            physics:
                const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(), // parent controll the scroll event
            itemCount: 44,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => Text("$index"),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ));
```

Comment: I got the idea, thanks for the insight

Answer (score 2):

As per your comment I think below link will helpful to you.

[Lists](https://newbedev.com/horizontal-listview-inside-a-vertical-scrollview-in-flutter)

Comment: The second example does look like what I needed, I think I got the logic down thanks

Answer (score 1):

I just added the below lines to your code. You can try the below code.

```dart
shrinkWrap: true,
physics: const  NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

```dart
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          ListView.builder(
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
              itemCount: 2,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: const  NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return const SuggestCard(
                  indexKey: 'takt',
                );
              }),
          FutureBuilder<AnimeDetails>(
            future: _animeDetail,
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: 2, //Number of anime from list
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    physics: const  NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      var anime = snapshot.data; //Get the data from the index
                      return AnimeCard(
                        anime: anime,
                      );
                    });
              } else {
                return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              }
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Comment: using `NeverScrollableScrollPhysics` on second `ListView` will block the scroll event

Comment: ListView handles all scrolling

Comment: yes bro bt try `horizontal` scroll on second List